# Execute a command with every command line input

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'm trying to find out how I can add "strace -e trace=write" to .bash_profile or such so that every command line executed on the server has a log of what it had as output.

Any ideas how I can pipe every command line through strace without the user having to add strace to the beginning of each one.  The strace would save it to a file with that timestamp.

Comment: Be careful but — roughly `exec strace -f -o very.big.file.very.quickly bash -l` would almost do the job.  You'd just need to stop that happening every time you run a shell.  It might be that you need `bash -i` instead of `bash -l`.  Or you need code in `.bashrc` to detect whether this is a top-level shell.  You need to be cautious because a mistake will give you an infinite loop.

Comment: Yea I only want the write portion which is considerably smaller.  Mainly I'm trying to capture the output of any command ran by a user.  Similar to if " ___ | tee file.txt" was run after each command.  So it would need to run on everything when a user logs in without them having to type it in

Comment: You may need to hook syscall `execve`.

Comment: Are you looking to capture the output sent to the terminal, or anything written by anything? These are 2 very different goals.

Comment: If you just want a log of the user's interactions with the terminal, use `script` instead of `strace`

Comment: @LeeDuhem trying to capture the command line a user put in and the output that he saw as a result of that command line

Comment: How is the user entering commands? telnet? ssh? serial console?  If serial-console only, it would be fairly straightforward to modify your init system to start `script` instead of something like `getty` or `login`.  If *also* connecting through ssh or telnet, you might need a light wrapper to generate a unique filename for each connection and then set that wrapper to be the user's shell in `/etc/passwd`.